# VirtualBox 5.2.10 unstable, how to revert to an older version

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I did a dist-upgrade to Bionic Beaver recently. The version of VirtualBox has gone to a newer version since that upgrade. I noticed some bugs that have been discussed on this site already but I could not find a solution yet. Because I use VirtualBox professionally and I have several customer computers simulated in a box, I want to downgrade to a lower version of VirtualBox to be able to continue work.

- The menu in full screen disappeared, I need to leave full screen before I can minimize the box.
- The mouse freezes, Leaving full screen mode and going back to full screen handles that.
- Full screen does not work properly with multiple monitors. I cannot change the monitor used for fullscreen mode.

As you can see, I have found a workaround to continue work but I find it annoying to work like this.

I have decided that I want to revert to the older version but I have simply no idea what version I was running on my old system (Xenial). Also what is the best way to get the old version back and avoid the upgrade to 5.2 on the next update.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First I tried this:

```
apt purge virtualbox
apt install virtualbox-5.1
apt-mark hold virtualbox
```

Starting the virtual machine failed with error: VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912)

Then this:

```
apt remove --purge virtualbox*
apt install virtualbox-5.1
apt-mark hold virtualbox
```

Then I got an error about USB 3.0 not working. 
I disabled USB in machine settings.
Started the machine again and reinstalled vbox extensions to get the matching version.

The menu is still missing, multi monitor systems do not work properly yet.

But I got rid of the freezing mouse problems.

Comment: USB 3.0 is enabled with the VirtualBox Extension Pack in the `virtualbox-ext-pack` APT package. If that doesn't work, you can uninstall VirtualBox and `virtualbox-ext-pack`, add `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` containing `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib`, then run `sudo apt update; sudo apt install virtualbox-5.2`, install the extension pack [downloaded from Oracle's site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds) (don't use `virtualbox-ext-pack`, since it's probably set to work for Ubuntu's version of VirtualBox).

Comment: If 5.2 from Oracle doesn't work for you, you can `sudo apt purge virtualbox-5.2; sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1` and then get and install the appropriate VirtualBox Extension Pack for your 5.1 version from their website.